# Function Definitions for Interfaces

Tags: java, graphics

Hello I have an assignment for my Graphical Programming Paper which requires you to design a Tetris-like game. They give you a skeleton code to start off with which I have posted below. My question is in regards to the two interfaces at the end. Where do I write the Function Definitions for the the functions declared in the interfaces or how do I use/implement those Functions?

```
  public class Tetris {

     public static void createGUI()
     {
       final JFrame frame = new JFrame("159.235 - A2");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
       frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

    final GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard();
    contentPane.add(gameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            gameBoard.keyTyped(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            gameBoard.keyReleased(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                gameBoard.pauseGame();
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                gameBoard.keyPressed(e);
            }
        }
    });

    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // Note: you might want to add a button to start, pause, or resume the
    // game instead of automatically starting it here
    gameBoard.startGame();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            createGUI();
        }
    });
}



class GameBoard extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// the number of rows and columns on the game board
public static final int NUM_COLS = 10;
public static final int NUM_ROWS = 20;

// the size of each cell in pixels
public static final int CELL_SIZE = 20;

// the game board size in pixels
public static final int GAME_FIELD_WIDTH = NUM_COLS * CELL_SIZE;
public static final int GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT = NUM_ROWS * CELL_SIZE;

// the interval between game state updates
private int m_updateInterval = 500;

// a random number generator
private Random m_rng = new Random();

// the game timer initiates an upate to the game state
private final Timer m_gameTimer = new Timer(m_updateInterval,
        new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                advanceGameState();
            }
        });

// the game board, with [0][0] being the bottom left cell
private final Block[][] m_cells = new Block[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

// the currently active shape
private Shape m_currentShape = null;

private boolean m_gameOver = false;

public GameBoard()
{
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(GAME_FIELD_WIDTH + 1, GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GAME_FIELD_WIDTH + 1, GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT));
    setOpaque(true);

    // set-up the timer for the render loop
    m_gameTimer.setInitialDelay(m_updateInterval);
    m_gameTimer.setRepeats(true);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        rotateShape(m_currentShape);
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: // move down
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: // move left
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: // move right
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: // toggle pause / resume
        if (m_gameTimer.isRunning()) pauseGame();
        else startGame();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: // disable down key
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: // disable left key
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: // disable right key
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{}

public void startGame()
{
    if (!m_gameOver) m_gameTimer.start();
}

public void pauseGame()
{
    m_gameTimer.stop();
}

/**
 * Returns a randomly chosen shape.
 */
private Shape createRandomShape()
{
    final int numShapes = 7;
    // generate a random number
    final int shapeId = m_rng.nextInt(numShapes);
    // create a new instance of the shape with this ID
    final Shape shape = null; // e.g. new LineShape();
    return shape;
}

/**
 * Advances the game state by one time step.
 */
private void advanceGameState()
{
    if (m_gameOver) return;

    if (m_currentShape == null) {
        m_currentShape = createRandomShape();
    }

    // move the current shape down by one row if possible; check for full
    // rows when the shape can no longer move
}

/**
 * Rotates the given shape by one quadrant.
 * 
 * @return True on success, false if the move is not possible.
 */
private boolean rotateShape(final Shape shape)
{
    // final float theta = (float) (Math.PI / 2.); // 90 degree CCW
    // shape.rotate(theta);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g)
{
    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    final int height = getHeight();

    // flip the y-axis and translate to move (0,0) to the bottom left corner
    g2.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0., height));
    g2.transform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1., -1.));

    // paint all occupied cells
    for (int row = 0; row < m_cells.length; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < m_cells[row].length; ++col) {
            if (m_cells[row][col] != null) m_cells[row][col].draw(g2);
        }
    }

    // this might be a good place to paint all animated blocks...

    g2.dispose();
}
}


interface Block {

/**
 * Returns the {@link Shape} this block belongs to.
 */
Shape getShape();

/**
 * The row index of this block on the game board.
 */
int getRow();

/**
 * The column index of this block on the game board.
 */
int getColumn();

/**
 * Update the row index.
 */
void setRow(int row);

/**
 * Update the column index.
 */
void setColumn(int column);

/**
 * Apply the given transformation to the model space coordinates of this
 * block.
 */
void transform(AffineTransform transform);

/**
 * Draw this block in its current position on the game board.
 */
void draw(Graphics2D g2);

/**
 * The given transform, along with any additional animation related effects,
 * are applied to this draw only. They do not have a permanent affect on the
 * state of the block.
 * 
 * @param g2
 *            The graphics instance.
 * @param transform
 *            The transform to apply on top of any existing transforms.
 * @param progress
 *            The animation progress in the range [0.0, 1.0].
 */
void animateAndDraw(Graphics2D g2, AffineTransform transform,
        float progress);
}


interface Shape {
/**
 * Returns the {@link Block}s that make up this shape.
 */
Block[] getBlocks();

/**
 * Returns the shape's paint.
 */
Paint getPaint();

/**
 * Rotates the shape by the specified amount.
 * 
 * @param theta
 *            Angle in radians.
 */
void rotate(float theta);
```

}

Comment: Using a `KeyListener` on a `JFrame`, wow, that's not going to end well

Answer (score 1):

You create a class which implements the interfaces and you write the functionality within it those.

Take a closer look at [Interfaces and Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) and [Implementing an Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) for more deatils

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that implements that interface, meaning it includes the methods defined in the interface and does something useful with them.

```
class MyShape implements Shape {

    @Override
    public Block[] getBlocks() {
        // Code that returns Block array
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getPaint() {
        // Code that returns Paint object
    }
}
```

You can read more about interfaces [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).